How to infinite loop randomly sized instances along the multiple curves
Is it possible to add infinite curve looping animation to this setup alongside with keeping the start and the end of the curve in the same place? Thanks!



To keep the endpoints in the same place the solution seems to me lies in multiplying the inst sizes by offset fraction and adding this to the accumulated sizes field result before sampling the curve length. At the same time when fraction reach 1 the instance index needs to be offset as well. But I am struggling to assemly all this together (my setup so far). The result is jumping or the order is wrong as you can see here and here .
this is not solution, here the endpoints are changing its position.



another test, it loops well, just the speed is driven by incoming instance size here nodes
latest progress 4.2 blender file (just hit the play):


Explain your problem... there is absolutely no information about what you want and what is wrong with what you have.

@DanielMöller - fixed, hope its more clear now...

@filanek Your file is in Blender 4.3, which hasn't been released yet. Your setup isn't working with 4.2.3.

I am sorry @Lutzi, fixed above in the last edit

I edited my answer, take a look

@Daniel Möller, many thanks, Dan. You put a lot of effort into this, and I feel a bit bad having to say this, but the setup is still the same. Offsetting the distance back and adding more points isn’t a solution, as you quickly run out of time. Imagine having 50,000 instances on 200 curves, where you'd need to keep twice as many points just for this short loop. I realize now that I didn’t specify it should be an infinite loop—my BIG mistake. I’ll leave the question open for a few more days, and before it expires, I'll award you the bounty. I'm sorry, and thank you again!

Actually, the question has already received the attention I needed, generally you replied to what I asked, so here’s the bounty. If someone finds a solution in the future, they’re still welcome to reply.

1. Index and Distance Mapping
This is the solution I have been able to achieve so far. However, it only loops the instances as they are distributed along the points:

I set all points on the resampled curve to zero, with all endpoints set to the spline length.
I then use the accumulated field, adding the time/offset modulated by the total value.

Next, I set the X position of the curve points to these values (from step 2) and adjust these points to a new curve, weighting the X position.

Finally, I sample the X and instance index values from this curve and use them as input for the sample curve node applied to the original curve.


nodes:

2. Unfinished Attempt at Index Shift
For this attempt, I add a time-to-index shift (row addition) along with an accumulated field. This also involves adding the first instance X value, multiplied by the time fraction.
In this solution, the points move only by the time fraction and should theoretically shift the indices infinitely. However, as you can see in the examples below, this method distorts time by the instance-added X, and currently works only for instances with the same length.
index shift only:

index shift + fraction:

same length:

nodes:

If anyone has suggestions on how this method could be completed, please let me know.


OK so what you want is to animate shapes moving through multiple splines, teleporting from spline's n end to spline's n+1 start, and from the last spline's end to the first spline start? It's also not clear how the teleportation should look, you could use boolean to cut objects at the ends of splines so that they look like moving through portals.

does not have to be from one spline to another, if my setup looks like this, its just my inexperience, in the original file booleans are involved, at this moment I even do not need this anymore, as still learning I am curious if this can be solved...

Here is a working proposal:
I decided to use named attributes because things were driving me crazy (especially the bounding box thing)

Store Len and Index
This node stores the index and length of the curbs in their respective points, so we can get them later with little complexity.
It also stores the original length of the resampled curve (since setting positions later will change this length)
My bounding box approach was looping the curb collection (backwards so we don't modify already stored items when we join selected and unselected). I couldn't find a way to use bounding box like a normal person, the behavior is weird.

Point positions
This is actually very simple.
I used the same accumulate method you used, having start positions and end positions.
I use the scene time just to displace the positions constantly, no treatment necessary (this means constant speed)
We use a start offset to put the positions way before the start of the curve (so you have more and more curbs coming in while time passes, at some point you will run out of curbs - in this case increase the negative offset and add more samples to the curve if needed)
Finally, for setting the actual point positions, we clip lengths below zero and above the original length.

Selections
Here, we allow only the curbs whose length are between "one curb before start" and "one curb after end". We need these extra spaces for the curbs that are being scaled at the start and end.

Scale and rotation
We just get two consecutive points, make the difference and use that as location and scale

File


Alternative solution to keep small number of curbs
This alternative explores the initial idea of a floored modulo, but for consistency, the modulo should take the total "curb" length (not curve). The main changes are in the point position group.

There are other changes in the file, but they follow the same principles explained earlier.
The main caveat is that in scale and rotation, "point offset" was not considering individual splines, so I had to sample end positions there.
New file


Thanks @Daniel Möller, I cannot change the amount of the points (it is estimated on the start and has to be bigger), this is just part of large nodetree and the curve endpoints have to stay in place. When you open my latest 4.2 file (at the bottom of my question there is something similar I am using total for the floored modulo and it works with more points, but this solution moves the endpoints. PS: there can be adaptive or fixed spacing both have to be with no gaps, for that reason I want the loop will happen just inbetween endpoints not changing their positions.

@filanek, Question 1: Do you understand that using "random discrete sizes", you are unable to make the curbs match the length of the curve? So, how do you want to deal with that? If there can be no gap, can we shrink the curve? Or is it ok for the curbs to overlap? /// Questoin 2: Why do you need end points to stay in place? Do you understand that this will make the start and/or end curbs not move at all? What prevents you from using the original curve as output and have the moving points only for curb placing?

Please take some time to explain your "exact goal". It's not possible to understand what you want just with pictures like that. And we can't distinguish between what you "want" and what your "attempt is doing" without a clear detailed explanation.

generally it should be possible to use the "floored modulo" method, but to sacrifice heaps of work and already made solutions. It will bring many new situations I will have to solve. It would take me a very long time to formulate all situations and try to explain in my poor english. So for that reason I just want to keep the question as simple as it is without the background.

If I find the answer to my question, it will make all adaptations a lot easier. Let's see if this file explains better what I want (open please and hit the play). The small spheres show the underlying points 11 stay in place. Just the speed is wrong - try to imagine it is constant - it is the result I am after. https://blend-exchange.com/b/bQgavyPm

So... if you have a file with the result you want... what is your question, then?

this is just an attempt to find solution, but this approach based on X size and index shift affect that the speed is not constant and it is wrong;(

You must tell us what you "want". Find solution for "what"? Please answer EACH of these questions: 1 - In the last file, if we make speed constant, is it a solution? // 2 - The curbs in the file are shrinking. Is this ok? // Please also answer the two questions I asked earlier.  --- Seriously, we still don't know what you "want". -

earlier:Question 1: YES (dealing you see on shrinking instances) Question 2: I do not want to move these points at all. What prevents me described in comment nr4.  last: 1 YES, 2YES shrinking or cut by boolean,

Great. Another question: curbs are shrinking in very sharp curves (make a very sharp 180 curve and watch). Is this ok? (If not, the complexity will increase a lot)

Yes I am splitting the curves in sharp angles to more segments so if I understand well this should not be a problem. Or if you mean that the length of long curb is longer in very curved curves (there is overhang at the end) I am using correction for this. Only thing I need to handle is how to loop inbetween two points and it is not possible without index shifting if I want to keep them in place. And big thanks you wasting your time on this...

I hope I am correct here, it should be something like in this rough description: https://i.imgur.com/GTZqxd1.jpeg

@filanek, I updated the solution using the initial "floored modulo" suggestion. Now you can use few curbs (but not too few). I just couldn't avoid a line connecting end to start in non loop splines.

Thanks, @Daniel Möller! This is a great solution if I can't find a way to shift the indices. I'm currently exploring a more "mechanical" approach with  infinite -  nodes.

Could I ask why you chose to avoid "the bounding box thing" approach and used the repeat zone instead? Performance-wise (especially with many instances), it seems a bit slower and reverses the order of instances, although that could be easily adjusted repeat timing. For similar performance reasons, I'm also trying to avoid named attributes, as I've heard they can slightly impact the performance.

@filanek, the bouding box is a "single" value, it's calculated once. And the loop has 4 iterations only, also calculated once. Performace-wise, it should be better, actually, because you're storing a named attribute once and never touching the bounding boxes again. I fail to understand how a named attribute could be slower than recalculating everything that is used multiple times.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

thanks for the explanation, still learning, but when I do some tests with many instances (repeat zone vs BB thing) the timing difference is significant as posted before https://i.imgur.com/9biviVQ.jpeg

You can represent randomized sizes as start/end points on the curves, then you can just shift them on the curve using modulo as in Daniel's answer:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Imgur mirror


Thanks @Markus von Broady this generally similar setup I have in example above "this is not solution, here the endpoints are changing its position." I am using total as floored modulo there.

endpoints stay in place https://i.imgur.com/C2PfHjo.gif (index shifting) VS endpoints moving https://i.sstatic.net/GmxL5dQE.gif floored modulo

hope this makes it more clear NOT https://i.imgur.com/wY7EAXd.gif YES https://i.imgur.com/GiwAceL.gif

@filanek what is the goal? If the goal is move blocks on a curve, then you achieve it like in my answer (I just realized my size calculation is "wrong" because it uses euclidean distance instead of distance on a curve - spline parameter: length difference between the points; but then again, the "right" calculation would probably produce more overlapping). But if you want to move all points of the curve along the curve, then you must understand this has to change the curve's shape, you can minimize the change, but imagine a 3-point triangle curve and moving its points, it has to morph...

"@Markus von Broady This is part of a much more complex node tree with packed rotations, booleans at the ends, instances with fixed or adaptive lengths, separate instances added at corners, etc. It includes features based on 11 fixed positions. If there’s a way to create an infinite loop between these 11 fixed endpoints (with index shifting and transformation), it would make things much easier. There are always challenges, but clever minds here often find solutions. My latest progress is close… yet still a bit far off." https://i.imgur.com/C2PfHjo.gif

@filanek Just because a setup is complex, doesn't mean the principle in a simple setup can't apply. I don't know your project, and doing the guesswork would take a lot more space than a comment size allows, but it's possible your approach to the problem is simply wrong and complexity of the setup only disguise this fact. In the end of the day it is your job as OP to find a way to represent your problem in generalized terms clear enough to constitute a good question on SE network.

I agree, it is just point I am in my naivity just right now and at this moment I cannot imagine other way...;( I want to keep the question simple and even it maybe does not have a solution I hope it is clear.
