GN_Instances with boundaries on spline
I'd like to make instances with boundaries scatter on spline



(1) Do you mean that instanced objects should be in contact, without the gaps highlighted with red crosses ? (2) Because it is unlucky that the spline length matches perfectly the sum of instanced objects width, how do you what to manage shorter/longer curves ?

Rather option (1) I'd like to have instances boundaries start from instance end and so on . It'd be great to function also in looped splines

@Mateusz88 2 questions have been asked, it would help to adress both of them if you hope for answer.

Take a look at this question. It places the instances with no gaps and no overlaps, but this statement is valid for the "center line". Now, if you say you want something that creates a gap in the middle because the sides are touching, then that would be a pretty hard heavy math solution
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/326230/how-to-infinite-loop-randomly-sized-instances-along-the-multiple-curves/326374#326374
